# Name variables in a model using TensorFlow 1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope

It seems like TensorFlow1.14 will automatically name variables in a model by order if you don't do that. For example:

```
Conv_1/weights:0
Conv_1/biases:0
BatchNorm_1/beta:0
Conv_2/weights:0
Conv_2/biases:0
BatchNorm_2/beta:0
Conv_3/weights:0
Conv_3/biases:0
BatchNorm_3/beta:0
```

I hope to keep these and add a head "net1", like this:

```
net1/Conv_1/weights:0
net1/Conv_1/biases:0
net1/BatchNorm_1/beta:0
```

And then, I need to initialize a same architecture with a different name, like:

```
net2/Conv_1/weights:0
net2/Conv_1/biases:0
net2/BatchNorm_1/beta:0
```

However, I can't simply change the scope in each layer to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with tf.variable_scope("net1") before the definition of your network instead of with tf.name_scope("net1"). Hope this can help more people.